# How to inherit Template Functions?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am required to inherit a templated class for a project. This is what it looks like:

LinkedListInterface.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class LinkedListInterface
{
public:
    LinkedListInterface(void) {}
    virtual ~LinkedListInterface(void) {}

    virtual void insertHead(T value) = 0;
    virtual void insertTail(T value) = 0;
};
```

That's what they gave us, and now I need to make a class that inherits from that and then does various functions. I can't for the life of me figure out the proper format. This is what I have so far:

LinkedList.h

```
#include "LinkedListInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<class T>
{
private:
    int   listsize;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    LinkedList(void) {}
    virtual ~LinkedList(void) {}

    void insertHead(T value) {}
    void insertTail(T value) {}
};
```

My issue is that it wont let me use `T`, it says `Incomplete type is not allowed`. Any insight on how to inherit this so I can use `T` would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedList` needs to be a class template with template parameter `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<T>
{
  ....
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to either be a template itself or derive from a specialized version of LinkedListInterface:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<T>
{
    ...
};
```

Or:

```
class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<int>
{
    ...
    void insertHead(int value){ }
    void insertTail(int value){ }
};
```